# Is Glass Armor obtainable at level 1 in Solsthiem?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is Glass Armor obtainable at level 1 in Solsthiem,
and if so how much luck is involved with each method to find it?

Comment: In case the answer is *no*: How would one go and prove it? The construction kit offers no easy way of seeing which leveled lists contain glass armor or a character wearing glass armor, and looking through *all of them* is a lot of effort.

Answer (score 11):

No.

Glass armor does not appear in leveled lists until you are [level 36](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glass_Armor#Glass_Armor). Allegedly they can appear in boss chests or merchant inventories at around [level 26](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Armor_(Skyrim)).

You can find a pickaxe and mine malachite from the [Glacial Cave](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Glacial_Cave) or [Nchardak](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Nchardak), assuming you could survive there at level one. However you can't craft glass armor without the requisite perk, which requires 70 Smithing, which you can't really get without leveling up a few times.

There are very few fixed sources of glass armor; [Northwatch Keep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Northwatch_Keep) and the [Thalmor Embassy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thalmor_Embassy) have guaranteed Thalmor spawns, but they won't be wearing glass armor until you're level 36. They're in Skyrim anyhow, not Solsthiem. I don't think Solstheim has any fixed spawns of the armor or creatures that would wear the armor.

Your best bet for getting it as early as possible is probably to level *only* Smithing until you hit 70 (to keep your level as low as possible), taking the appropriate perks along the way, and then make a beeline for a malachite ore vein and craft the armor yourself.

Or to cheat.